# How can I use Lighting as calendar app with Gnome 3 Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, calendar, lightning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change Gnome Shell calendar default application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69349/how-to-change-gnome-shell-calendar-default-application)

How can I use Lighting as default instead the already removed Evolution calendar app with Gnome 3 Shell? I am on 11.10/64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow the instruction replied [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69349/how-to-change-gnome-shell-calendar-default-application) but as they say there is no sync with calendar interface, only opens lightening instead of doing nothing