# How can I set Beatbox as default music player?

Tags: gnome, default-programs, music-player, beatbox

I have installed `Beatbox` but I can't set it as default music player in `System Configuration` of Gnome-shell. How can I set it manually?

---

I add information:
BeatBox can't be actually define like default audio player in Gnome: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beat-box/+bug/972956
I want to know how can I define **manually** the **default audio player** in the same manner that I can define the default calendar app: [How to change Gnome Shell calendar default application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69349/how-to-change-gnome-shell-calendar-default-application)

Answer (score 0):

Click on Applications --> System Tools --> system settings, once it opens

[image]

Click on Details, and then Default Applications, and choose BeatBox from the music menu.

[image]

Here is how I got beatbox to be the default.  I just installed BeatBox with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sgringwe/beatbox
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install beatbox
```

I opened Ubuntu Tweaks, and clicked on File Type Manager, 
[image]

and changed all the Audio to BeatBox instead of Rhythmbox.

Comment: Like I said: "_I can't set it as default music player in System Configuration of Gnome-shell._"  See this Beatbox bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beat-box/+bug/972956

Comment: Take a look at the added info.

Comment: I want define in Gnome Shell the default audio player. That solution only define the default audio player for each mime-type and for that I don't need install ubuntu-tweak.