# Calendar doesn't open in GNOME 3

Tags: 12.04, gnome, calendar

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and a few days back i installed the GNOME 3 shell. Upon clicking the Date/Time bar in the top centre position of the screen, there is a drop down menu which contains an option called `Open Calendar`, upon clicking that i get the following error:

`Execution of 'evolution -c calendar' failed: Command not found.`

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install evolution to use the calendar option in Gnome 3:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

There is another method if you need to set up Thunderbird or Chromium check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70743/169736). But remember, this won't sync the calendar, nor tasks